# Reading double byte files

Tags: file-io, tcl

I was wondering if there was a simple way in Tcl to read a double byte file (or so I think it is called). My problem is that I get files that look fine when opened in notepad (I'm on Win7) but when I read them in Tcl, there are spaces (or rather, null characters) between each and every character.

My current workaround has been to first run a `string map` to remove all the null

```
string map {\0 {}} $file
```

and then process the information normally, but is there a simpler way to do this, through [`fconfigure`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/fconfigure.htm), [`encoding`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/encoding.htm) or another way?

I'm not familiar with encodings so I'm not sure what arguments I should use.

```
fconfigure $input -encoding double
```

of course fails because `double` is not a valid encoding. Same with 'doublebyte'.

I'm actually working on big text files (above 2 GB) and doing my 'workaround' on a line by line basis, so I believe that this slows the process down.

---

EDIT: As pointed out by @mhawke, the file is UTF-16-LE encoded and this apparently is not a supported encoding. Is there an elegant way to circumvent this shortcoming, maybe through a `proc`? Or would this make things more complex than using `string map`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to write a little proc to convert the file. I am using a `while` loop since reading a 3 GB file into a single variable locked the process completely... The comments make it seem pretty long, but it's not that long.

```
proc itrans {infile outfile} {
  set f [open $infile r]

  # Note: files I have been getting have CRLF, so I split on CR to keep the LF and
  # used -nonewline in puts
  fconfigure $f -translation cr -eof ""

  # Simple switch just to remove the BOM, since the result will be UTF-8
  set bom 0                              
  set o [open $outfile w]
  while {[gets $f l] != -1} {
    # Convert to binary where the specific characters can be easily identified
    binary scan $l H* l

    # Ignore empty lines
    if {$l == "" || $l == "00"} {continue}

    # If it is the first line, there's the BOM
    if {!$bom} {
      set bom 1

      # Identify and remove the BOM and set what byte should be removed and kept
      if {[regexp -nocase -- {^(?:FFFE|FEFF)} $l m]} {
        regsub -- "^$m" $l "" l

        if {[string toupper $m] eq "FFFE"} {
          set re "(..).."
        } elseif {[string toupper $m] eq "FEFF"} {
          set re "..(..)"
        }
      }
      regsub -all -- $re $l {\1} new
    } else {
      # Regardless of utf-16-le or utf-16-be, that should work since we split on CR
      regsub -all -- {..(..)|00$} $l {\1} new
    }
    puts -nonewline $o [binary format H* $new]
  }
  close $o
  close $f
}

itrans infile.txt outfile.txt
```

Final warning, this will mess up characters actually using all 16 bits (e.g. code unit sequence `04 30` will lose the `04` and become `30` instead of becoming `D0 B0` [as it should be in Table 3-4](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode7.0.0/ch03.pdf#G7404), but `00 4D` will correctly be mapped to `4D`) in a character silently, so be sure you don't mind that or your file doesn't contain such characters before trying out the above.

Answer (score 1):

The input files are probably UTF-16 encoded as is common in Windows.

Try:

```
% fconfigure $input -encoding unicode
```

You can get a list of encodings using:

```
% encoding names
cp860 cp861 cp862 cp863 tis-620 cp864 cp865 cp866 gb12345 gb2312-raw cp949 cp950 cp869 dingbats ksc5601 macCentEuro cp874 macUkraine gb2312 jis0201 euc-cn euc-jp iso8859-10 macThai iso2022-jp jis0208 macIceland iso2022 iso8859-13 jis0212 iso8859-14 iso8859-15 cp737 iso8859-16 big5 euc-kr macRomania gb1988 iso2022-kr macTurkish macGreek ascii cp437 macRoman iso8859-1 iso8859-2 iso8859-3 koi8-r iso8859-4 macCroatian ebcdic cp1250 iso8859-5 iso8859-6 macCyrillic cp1251 iso8859-7 cp1252 koi8-u macDingbats iso8859-8 cp1253 cp1254 iso8859-9 cp1255 cp850 cp932 cp1256 cp852 cp1257 identity cp1258 macJapan utf-8 shiftjis cp936 cp855 symbol cp775 unicode cp857
```

Comment: Doing this also gives me a lot of `?` while those were not present in the original file. For instance, I have a date-time value in the file `26-MAR-2014 22:03:47` and this is becoming `26-MAR-2?????? 3:47`. Maybe that could help identify the encoding?

Comment: I also opened the file in a Hex editor and the first two bytes are `FF FE`, if that helps.

Comment: 0xFF 0XFE is a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16) that indicates that the file is encoded as UTF-16 with little endian order. So the file should definitely be considered as UTF-16-LE. But it seems that in Tcl "unicode" is not clearly specified (depends on native platform), and there is no utf-16-le or utf-16-be encoding options.

Comment: That's useful! I realise I should have tried reading deeper into BOMs. I stumbled on the utf-8 version in the past and have been removing them since those files wouldn't be used outside a particular program. In any case, that's a bit sad to learn. I wonder if there's a way now to circumvent that shortcoming =/. I've been getting files like this a lot more recently (as opposed to utf-8 ones). Thanks for your input.

Comment: Perhaps you could pre-process the files, or call out to an external tool. `iconv` is good at converting files between encodings.