# (Tcl) what character encoding set should I use?

Tags: encoding, tcl

So I'm trying to open and parse some old Visual Studio compilation log files with Tcl; my only problem is the files are in a strange encoding. Upon examining them with Notepad++ it seems they are in the 'UCS-2 Little Endian' encoding. Two questions:

- Is there any command in Tcl that allows me to look at the character encoding of a file? I know there is `encoding system` which tells me the system encoding.
- Using `encoding names` Tcl tells me the available encoding names are the following list:

  cp860 cp861 cp862 cp863 tis-620 cp864 cp865 cp866 gb12345 gb2312-raw cp949 cp950 cp869 dingbats ksc5601 macCentEuro cp874 macUkraine jis0201 gb2312 euc-cn euc-jp macThai iso8859-10 jis0208 iso2022-jp macIceland iso2022 iso8859-13 jis0212 iso8859-14 iso8859-15 cp737 iso8859-16 big5 euc-kr macRomania macTurkish gb1988 iso2022-kr macGreek ascii cp437 macRoman iso8859-1 iso8859-2 iso8859-3 macCroatian koi8-r iso8859-4 ebcdic iso8859-5 cp1250 macCyrillic iso8859-6 cp1251 macDingbats koi8-u iso8859-7 cp1252 iso8859-8 cp1253 iso8859-9 cp1254 cp1255 cp850 cp1256 cp932 identity cp1257 cp852 macJapan cp1258 shiftjis utf-8 cp855 cp936 symbol cp775 unicode cp857

  Given this, what would be the appropriate name to use in the `fconfigure -encoding` command to read these `UCS-2 Little Endian`encoded files and convert them to `UTF-8` for use? If I understand the `fconfigure` command correctly, I need to specify the encoding type of the source file rather than what I want it to be; I just don't know which of the options in the above list corresponds to `UCS-2 Little Endian`. After reading a little bit, I see that UCS-2 is a predecessor of the UTF-16 character encoding, but that option isn't here either.

Thanks!

Comment: [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27101085/720999)

Comment: Strictly, `encoding system` returns the encoding used for _filenames_ and other strings passed to OS calls (other than for reads and writes on channels). It's also the default encoding for channels, but you can change that. Almost all the time, you never change the system encoding; Tcl typically gets it right. The exceptions are for where things are _very_ gnarly, such as a removable filesystem mounted with a different encoding…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid, currently there's no way to do it just by using `fconfigure -encoding ?something?`: the `unicode` encoding has rather moot meaning, and there's a [feature request](http://sourceforge.net/p/tcl/feature-requests/392/) to create explicit support for UTF-16 variants.

What you could do about it?

Since `unicode` in Tcl running on Windows *should* mean UTF-16 with native endianness<sup>1</sup> (little-endian on Wintel), if your solution is supposed to be a quick and dirty one, just try using `-encoding unicode` and see if that helps.

If you're targeting at some more bullet-proof or future-proof of cross-platform solution, I'd switch the channel to binary more, read the contents in chunks of two bytes at a time, and then use

```
binary scan $twoBytes s n
```

to [scan the sequence of two bytes](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/binary.htm#M50) in `$twoBytes` as an 16-bit integer into a variable named "n", followed by something like

```
set c [format %c $n]
```

to [produce a unicode character out of the number](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/format.htm#M23) in $n, and assign it to a variable.

This way supposedly requires a bit more trickery to get correctly:

- You might check the very first character obtained from the stream to see if it's a byte-order-mark, and drop it if it is.
- If you need to process the stream in a line-wise manner, you'd have to implement a little state machine that would handle the CR+LF sequences correctly.
- When doing your `read $channelId 2`, to get the next character, you should check that it returned not just 0 or 2, but also 1 — in case the file happens to be corrupted, — and handle this.

---

The UCS-2 encoding differs from UTF-16 in that the latter might contain the so-called surrogate pairs, and hence *it is not a fixed-length encoding.*  Hence handling an UTF-16 stream properly implies also detecting those surrogate pairs.  On the other hand, I hardly beleive a compilation log produced by MSVS might contain them, so I'd just assume it's encoded in UCS-2LE.

---

<sup>1</sup> The true story is that the only thing Tcl guarantees about *textual* strings it handles (that is, those obtained by maniputating text, not via `binary format` or `encoding convertto` or reading a stream in binary mode) is that they're Unicode (or, rather, the "BMP" part of it).
But technically, the interpreter might switch the internal representation of any string between the UTF-8 encoding it uses by default and *some* fixed-length encoding which is what is referred to by that name "unicode". The "problem" is that no part of Tcl documentation specifies that internal fixed-length encoding because you're *required* to explicitly convert any text you output or read to/from some specific encoding — either via configuring the stream or using `encoding convertfrom` and `encoding convertto` or using `binary format` and `binary scan`, and the interpreter will do the right thing no matter which precise encoding it's currently using for your source string value — it's all transparent.  Moreover, the next release of the "standard" Tcl interpreter might decide to drop this internal feature completely, or, say, use 32-bit or 64-bit integers for that internal fixed-length encoding.  Whatever "non-standard" interpreters do (like `Jacl` etc) are also up to them.  In other words, this feature is internal and is not a part of the documented contract about the interpreter's behaviour.  And by the way, the "standard" encoding for Tcl strings (UTF-8) is not specified as such either — it's just an implementation detail.

Comment: Phew; looks like I have a lot of work to do. Thanks for the detailed and informational post, I've learned a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In Tcl v8.6.8 I could solve the same issue with fconfigure channelId -encoding unicode.